# Testing for warning if JavaScript not enabled with Behat/Mink

Tags: php, symfony, behat, mink

I have a simple scenario:

```
Scenario: No javascript warning
    Given I am on homepage
    When I don't have javascript enabled
    Then I should see a warning
```

How would I implement the when part with mink? Is there a more elegant way than just testing for a noscript element?

My solution so far:

```
/**
 * @When /^I don\'t have javascript enabled$/
 */
public function iDonTHaveJavascriptEnabled()
{
    $driver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
    if ($driver instanceof BrowserKitDriver or $driver instanceof GoutteDriver) {
        return true;
    }

    throw new UnsupportedDriverActionException(
        'Scenario needs to be tested with a javascript disabled driver',
        $driver
    );
}

/**
 * @Then /^I should see a warning$/
 */
public function iShouldSeeAWarning()
{
    $this->assertElementOnPage('noscript');
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<noscript>You're only spoiling things for yourself!</noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks, how to implement it for a visitor is clear but I'd like to test against it...

Comment: I see.. could you have some ajax form submit if it is enabled? updating a session value to true for example? I am not familiar with behat or mink myself.

Comment: Yes... The question is more how to make mink behave as if it had no JavaScript enabled...